How do I multiple an Excel Range by 1 using Office Script?
How can I multiple the selected range in Excel using Office Script by 1?
I'm trying to use the Excel trick of converting dates and numbers that aren't dates and numbers into being so by multiplying by 1.
I can easily do this in VBA but I was looking for Office Script solution as this is then available for all files regardless.
I can't find a method that will allow me to iterate over the selected cells.
Thanks

Are you trying to convert a date stored in Excel to a JavaScript Date object? If so, this sample might help: JavaScript Date samples.
